# How could I log user-specific information (IP address etc) into a table?

Tags: php, mysql, logging, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the client's IP address in a PHP webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437771/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-a-php-webservice)

I've a small site that lets anonymous users to upload images. However, this obviously has the potential to be abused. How could I track/log relevant information (IP address etc) for each image that is uploaded? I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks.

Comment: What part of doing this is your question about - serving the image, writing data into a database...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $_SERVER
>
> 'REMOTE_ADDR'  The IP address from which the user is viewing the
>   current page.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

You can find how to get relevant data for each user.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

to getting the IP address of the user who upload the image,
you just add the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to the image upload script,
and you will get the IP address of the user.