# A simple web application-user with log on information

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple web page in which the user will enter some information before submitting the form. I would like to retrieve his IPaddress after the post is done.

Comment: please look into $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is function from [another relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437771/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-a-php-webservice) that should help:

```
function getUserIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) //if from shared
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //if from a proxy
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
```

This will cover the occasional proxy user and shared networks.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work:

```
<?php 
   echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
?>
```