# Grabbing an IP Address without needing to turn on Register Globals

Tags: php, security, ip-address, session-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the client's IP address in a PHP webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437771/how-can-i-get-the-clients-ip-address-in-a-php-webservice)

I'm wanting to grab the IP Address from the user but I don't want to turn register globals on in my php.ini file. Is there a way to work around this and still grab the ip address?

Comment: This all over the internet. Please use search before you ask.

Comment: I did do a search. I swear I read where you have to turn on register globals to grab the ip address.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=get+ip+php

Comment: Hey, I screwed up. I'm sorry. I requested to close the question so if 3 more people clicked close then this question can go to Purgatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register Globals is not required to obtain the IP Address, why would you think it is?

Get the IP:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: I must have read something wrong. Thanks for the quick reply.