# how to track ip address of email sender

Tags: php

I am using mail function in php, how to track or find the `IP address` of email sender.
here is my code.

```
mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

all parameter came from view page using `$_POST`.

Comment: Umm append `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to your `$message`?

Answer (score 3):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3358212/829533

Make a function in php

```
function getUserIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) //if from shared
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //if from a proxy
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
```

and add ip address to the email

```
$message = "IP Address: " . getUserIpAddr();
mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

Comment: you help hacker spoof ip easily by sening fake HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,
its better log all this ips